Starting pipewire on a server for a cron job
I have a cron job that plays an audio file using mpv on one of my home servers running Void Linux. I cannot hear any sound, until I ssh into the server and start pipewire manually, after which it works for all future cron job runs.
/usr/bin/pipewire &
/usr/bin/sleep 1
/usr/bin/pactl set-sink-volume @DEFAULT_SINK@ 100%
/usr/bin/mpv <path-to-the-audio-file>

I used full path for everything as I learned the crons are run in minimal environments where not everything is in $PATH. The sleep is to make sure pipewire is ready, as I've had an issue with setting the sink volume right after I start pipewire. It does seem to work for me elsewhere, so I used it here as well.
TL;DR: I need to ssh into the server and start pipewire at least once in order to get the audio to play.
Is there a way to have pipewire start even after a fresh reboot?

Setting XDG_RUNTIME_DIR to my user directory seems to do the trick.
So the cron script now becomes:
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/home/<my-user> /usr/bin/dbus-run-session /usr/bin/pipewire &
/usr/bin/sleep 1
/usr/bin/pactl set-sink-volume @DEFAULT_SINK@ 100%
/usr/bin/mpv <path-to-the-audio-file>

